# How to change tab child color on changing the tab's view

Tags: flutter, tabs, flutter-layout, containers, tabbar

I want to change tabs child which is a `Contianer`.

Right now, I am checking the controllers index which delays in changing the color.
something like this.

```
Tab(
    child: Container(
        color : controller.index == 2 ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
    )
)
```

[image: code screen shot]

Right now I am getting what I needed but there is a littel delay

Comment: i cant undrestand what is your problem, please explain it more, are you using getx and it doesnt update? what is wrong now

Comment: I have attached the Screen shot of code